# SDK Manager: установить дополнительный функционал

Tags: manager, sdk

У меня проблема. Когда я хочу из android studio захожу в sdk manager и пытаюсь установить дополнительный функционал у меня выбивает

> Fetching URL:
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
> Validate XML:
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
> Parse XML: 
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
> Found Google APIs (x86 System Image),
> Android API 19, revision 4 Fetching
> URL:
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
> Validate XML:
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
> Parse XML: 
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
> Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System
> Image, Android API 19, revision 1 Done
> loading packages. Preparing to install
> archives Downloading Android Support
> Repository, revision 5 Failed to
> create directory C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk\temp
> Downloading Android Support Library,
> revision 19.1 Failed to create
> directory C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk\temp
> Downloading Google USB Driver,
> revision 9 Failed to create directory
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk\temp
> Done. Nothing was installed.

Но что самое интересное тот функционал, который я хотел установить (результат выполнения приведен выше) нигде не видно
Посоветуйте как выйти из такого положения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите от имени администратора.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что у вас нет доступа к системному каталогу `Program Files`. Вам надо либо получить права админа либо просто установить SDK Manager на свой локальный каталог